# Print and report number of characters output

Tags: common-lisp

Given that I am calling `write` to output some value (might be an atom, list, dotted pair), is there a way to find out how many characters are written? Either before or after the call, or using some similar function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are writing to a [`file-stream`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/t_file_s.htm),
you can use [`file-position`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_file_p.htm)
before and after [`write`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_wr_pr.htm).

When the stream has no notion of a position (e.g., a [`broadcast-stream`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/t_broadc.htm)), one has to resort
to [`write-to-string`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_wr_to_.htm)
plus [`write-string`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_wr_stg.htm):

```
(defun write-and-count (object &rest args &key stream &allow-other-keys)
  "Write object to stream and return the number of characters written."
  (let ((start (ignore-errors (file-position stream))))
    (if start
        (progn              ; file stream
          (apply #'write object args)
          (- (file-position stream) start))
        (progn              ; something more complex
          (remf args :stream)
          (length (write-string (apply #'write-to-string object args) stream))))))

(with-open-file (s "foo" :direction :output)
  (write-and-count '(1 2 3) :stream s))
==> 7
(write-and-count '(1 2 3) :stream *standard-input*)
(1 2 3)    ; output
==> 7      ; return value
(write-and-count '(1 2 3))
(1 2 3)    ; output
==> 7      ; return value
```

**Notes**:

1. The `file-position` approach is just an optimization for huge objects.
2. [`remf`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_remf.htm) is needed to avoid a `illegal keyword/value pair` error in `write-to-string`.
3. Streams can be tricky; it is *not* guaranteed that `(write x :stream s)` is equivalent to `(write-string (write-to-string x) s)`. Think of the (widely implemented although not official) [Gray streams](http://www.nhplace.com/kent/CL/Issues/stream-definition-by-user.html): if you write to a [`broadcast-stream`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/t_broadc.htm) which broadcasts to an ordinary [`file-stream`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/t_file_s.htm) and a [pretty-printing](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/22_b.htm) [Gray stream](http://www.nhplace.com/kent/CL/Issues/stream-definition-by-user.html), you will [`write`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_wr_pr.htm) a *different* number of characters to the two streams. What would you expect the returned character count to be? 1st count? 2nd? Their sum?

Answer (score 2):

A more complex method would be to use *gray streams*, which is a CLOS based variant of I/O streams, once proposed by David N. Gray. Many implementations support it in some way. One can for example write new stream classes and write `:after` methods for the output functions, which would record the number of written characters.

Gray streams provide extensible CLOS based I/O streams.

I wouldn't be surprised if people have already written such functionality...

See [trivial gray streams](https://github.com/trivial-gray-streams/trivial-gray-streams) for a compatibility layer over several implementations.